# clearInterval does not stop the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So i wanted to create a setInterval function to spam my friends at a given time, it all works good except from clearInterval.

````js
module.exports = {
    name: 'sp',
    execute(message, args){
        let member = message.mentions.users.first();
        let times = args[1]
        let mspam = args.slice(2).join(' ')
        message.delete()
        if(message.author.id != '387597578893524992' && message.author.id != '341994639395520526'){
            let noperm = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Insufficient permissions.")
            .setDescription(`${message.author} You do not have permission to perfom this command.`)
            .setColor("#FF0000")
            .setTimestamp();
            return message.channel.send(noperm).then(msg =>{
                msg.delete({timeout: 10000})
            })
        }
        var spam = function spammy(){
            message.channel.send(`${member} ${mspam}`)
        }
        if(member){
            setInterval(spam, ms(times))
        }else if(!member){
            clearInterval(spam)
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: you need to pass interval into clearInterval

Answer (score 0):

You gotta handle your intervals correctly.

[`setInterval()` returns a handle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to an interval item when you set it. If you don't hang on to that item it returns you can't clear the interval.

[`clearInterval()` accepts that handle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) as its single parameter.

You can always search for "mdn setInterval" in your favorite search engine on the 'toobz to get the official documentation for setInterval or any part of Javascript (or HTML, CSS).

With respect, I will let you fix your own code.

Comment: Can you help me fix it please?